# merged column only display as first row

Tags: javascript, exceljs, sheetjs, js-xlsx

I have this excel format then will be import and display into html table.

[image: check here]

The participants will always have same Trainer so i just merged the trainer column
but the problem is when `console.log` it, it count as one row only.

Here's the code

```
    const Importssss = document.getElementById('importInput');
           var JSONExcel = function () {
               this.parseExcel = function (file) {
                   var reader = new FileReader();
               reader.onload = function (e) {
            var data = e.target.result;
            var excelBinary = XLSX.read(data, { type: 'binary' });
            excelBinary.SheetNames.forEach(function (sheetName) { // Reading each sheet data in excel
                var XL_row_object = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(excelBinary.Sheets[sheetName]);
                var json_object = JSON.stringify(XL_row_object); // json from excel
                var excelData = (JSON.parse(json_object)); // json parsed from excel
                console.log(excelData);
            })
        };
        reader.onerror = function (ex) {
            console.log(ex);
        };
        reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
    };
};

      Importssss.addEventListener('change', function (evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files;
    if (files.length !== 0) {
        var JSONConvert = new JSONExcel();
        JSONConvert.parseExcel(files[0]); // Pass to Excel Converter Function
    }
})
```

and this is the output

[image: output]

Expected output should not count as a first row but in all row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You can create a new array that keeps track of the last-named trainer

You can also simplify your code in several ways. Most importantly, there is no need for the `JSON.stringify` followed by `JSON.parse`. They cancel each other out, so just skip those two lines.

Just call `XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array`, but perhaps name the resulting variable explicitly like this:

```
const arrayOfRowsSkippingTrainer = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(excelBinary.Sheets[sheetName]);
```

Then you can create an array with the missing `Trainer` filled in:

```js
// const arrayOfRowsSkippingTrainer = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(excelBinary.Sheets[sheetName]);

const arrayOfRowsSkippingTrainer = [{
    Trainer: "T1",
    Participant: "P1",
    Subject: "S1",
    Score: "10"
  },
  {
    Participant: "P2",
    Score: "20",
    Subject: "S2",
  },
  {
    Participant: "P3",
    Score: "30"
  },
  {
    Trainer: "T2",
    Participant: "P4",
    Score: "40"
  },
  {
    Participant: "P5",
    Score: "50"
  },
  {
    Trainer: "T3",
    Participant: "P6",
    Score: "60"
  },
  {
    Trainer: "T4",
    Participant: "P7",
    Score: "70"
  },
]


let lastTrainer = "";
let lastSubject = "";
const arrayOfRows = arrayOfRowsSkippingTrainer.map(row => {
  if ("Trainer" in row) {
    lastTrainer = row.Trainer
  }
  if ("Subject" in row) {
    lastSubject = row.Subject
  }
  return { ...row,
    Trainer: lastTrainer,
    Subject: lastSubject,
  }
})

console.log(arrayOfRows)
```

Comment: How about i have two column, both have merge row. 
`if ("Trainer" in row && "Subject" in row )`

Comment: I've just updated to do that